# Android real time notification

Tags: android, notifications

I'm developing a payment app that will use QR Code. The customer will show his personal QR Code and the merchant will read the QR Code, enter the value of the purchase and send the information for a webservice. So the customer will be notified about the purchase, and will authorize.

My question is about the notification abouth the purchase for the customer. What is the best approach? I think use Timer, so the customer app will consult a webservice each 10 seconds to check if there are a new notification. But its probably the customer make just one purchase per day (or week!) with the app. So I think that a http request each 10 seconds its much requests for the necessity. By other way, the customer need receive the notification like real time to finish the purchase.

The is another approach for this function? Can I my webservice send a notification for the customer app when it receive the purchase request from the merchant?

I think what I want is the same mechanism that apps like Tinder or Badoo use, when the user receive a notification when he have a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Google Cloud Messaging **only** for notifications. GCM is a persistent connection which consumes much less power comparative to non-persistent connections to keep the notifications real time. Since all the applications use GCM as a standard for notifications, you shouldn't be using any other technique to do this because it will add to the consumption of battery.

Answer (score 1):

You should use GoogleCloudMessaging and remove those calls from your app. Once you get the event, you can send GCM a request from your server.
Here is an example of how to implement it in PHP:
https://github.com/mattg888/GCM-PHP-Server-Push-Message

Then implement a receiver that will handle that notification.

Or you can develop it all by yourself but there are so many libraries out there that you can use.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications are what you will want to use. You will have to go through Google Cloud Messaging (or perhaps another similar service to achieve this)

If you search for "Push Notifications" or "Google Cloud Messaging" You will find lots of reading about the subject to inform yourself.